# SAML 2.0 onelogin IdPMetadataParser returns empty result

Tags: java, xml-parsing, metadata, saml, onelogin

I' trying to parse an Idp metadata xml file of the SimpleSAMLphp tool with the java onelogin lib.

The result of **IdPMetadataParser.parseXML(...)** is always empty so I cannot get a valid Saml2Settings object.

My metadata xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" entityID="http://localhost:8666/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php">
    <md:IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDXTCCAkWg...</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDXTCCAkWg...</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://localhost:8666/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php"/>
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://localhost:8666/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php"/>
        <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost:8666/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php"/>
    </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

My code:

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new FileReader("metadata.xml")));

    Map<String, Object> metaData = IdPMetadataParser.parseXML(doc);
    // metaData is here empty

    Saml2Settings settings = new Saml2Settings();
    IdPMetadataParser.injectIntoSettings(settings, metaData);
}
catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It seems that the XPath implementation returns an empty result for the query "//md:EntityDescriptor/md:IDPSSODescriptor".

What am I doing wrong? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Don't make the xml Document object from the Builder. Instead, use OneLogin's Util method:

```
Document doc = Util.parseXML(new InputSource(new FileReader("metadata.xml")));
Map<String, Object> metaData = IdPMetadataParser.parseXML(doc);
assert !metaData.isEmpty();
Saml2Settings settings = new Saml2Settings();
IdPMetadataParser.injectIntoSettings(settings, metaData);
```

This should work even when the xml file is not on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

source : https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml/issues/177

final Map idpSettings = IdPMetadataParser.parseFileXML("idp-metadata.xml");
final Saml2Settings settings = new SettingsBuilder().fromValues(idpSettings).build();

Comment: You shuldn't just link to a third party site because the link could disappear therefor making it difficult to understand what you wanted to say. Instead you should describe whats causing the problem and the solution for that.

Comment: So use the parseFileXml method, and pass it the path to your IdP xml file, rather than making the document object yourself.

Comment: Don't just copy/paste someone else's code.  This isn't even your work... don't post it as such.  Furthermore, answers on Stack Overflow are expected to have some sort of explanation.  If you thought this link was relevant, you should have added it as a comment instead.